# How to share image data between applications?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I already have an application called "old" which renders an image in which the image data is stored in form of session, and I need to read that data from this existing "old" application to an application called "new".

How do I pass this data? Do I need to get the memory address of the session and pass it to my other application?

And even if I have the memory address how do I read the entire data? It has loads of data stored.

Named pipes and all the others create a link between two processes and when one process writes to a memory location the other process reads it.

But I have a memory address of one process as an input, isn't the only thing that I have to do is just read the data from that memory address from the other process?

Answer (score 4):

You have quite a few options to communicating between two processes

- Save the data to a file and read if from the other application
- Use a [named pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590(VS.85).aspx) to establish a connection
- Use a [named shared memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551(VS.85).aspx) created using win32 API calls
- Use a shared [memory area within a DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686958(VS.85).aspx) loaded from both applications

Answer (score 1):

As you are using C++ I would strongly suggest that you take a look at [Boost interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/interprocess.html). It provides nice platform independent access to interprocess communication, where most of the tedious and error prone low level details are shielded from you.

Answer (score 0):

Given the leanings of your question, I would suggest @shoosh's named shared memory suggestion. I've used that before for images from cameras and such as well.